# Can I use the hotel shuttles between McCarran Airport and the Strip without a hotel booking?

Tags: usa, airport-transfer, las-vegas, nevada, las

There appear to be many free hotel shuttles between McCarran International Airport and the Strip or the downtown. If I don't book a hotel, can I still use the shuttles? Can I also get back from some hotel on the Strip (or in the downtown) to the airport?

Comment: Don't hotel shuttles have lists of names ? even if they are free ?

Comment: @Max I don't know about Las Vegas (that's why I asked this question), but in Macau I've taken Wynn shuttles without staying there with no problems.

Comment: @Max In general from the airport to the hotel there is no name list.  From the hotel to the airport there may be a name list if you have to book a shuttle at a particular time during a busy period.  I also don't know about Las Vegas, but I have previously taken shuttles to hotels at LAX without a room booking.  However I have done so in order to use the gym so I can have a shower (and paid for the privilege)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, these shuttles are provided for hotel guests, not for anyone to use. Also, some cursory research by Googling seems to show that most major hotels on the strip do charge their guests for using the shuttle. The hotels that provide free shuttles tend to be not the ones you think of when you want to stay on the strip.

Those that do offer a free shuttle service seem to all include a disclaimer similar to this one (happens to be the first one I found on Google, emphasis mine):

> Silver Sevens offers complimentary shuttle service to and from the
>   McCarran Airport, **exclusively for registered hotel guests**.